# Replace local images with base 64

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

I am building some emails template in which I include some local pictures.

I am trying to write a shell script to replace turn my images to base64. So basically automatically turn:

```
        <img width="100%" src="./img/my_image.gif" />
```

to

```
    <img width="100%" src="data:image/gif;base64,XXXXXXX" />
```

For now I used this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -F'[()]' -v q="'" '

/src="(.*)"/ {
    cmd=sprintf("openssl enc -base64 -in %s | tr -d %c\\n%c",$2,q,q)
    cmd | getline b64
    close(cmd)
    $0=$1 "(data:image/gif;base64," b64 ");"
}1' ./my_template.html
```

I run into two issues:
- my regex doesn't seem to be correct even though it worked fine on regex101
- this regex would also catch the images which are not local (src="https://....")

How can I tweak it to make it work here?

Comment: Can you explain more on your actual requirment than how your actual attempt and how it failed? With a minimal input and an expected verifiable output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your file, but IMHO editing html using awk isn't the best idea. In the general, i would to use better tool, like `perl` and such.

Here is an example using `xmlstarlet`. The following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

htmlfile=t.html

encode_image() {
        local img="$1"
        ext="${img##*.}"
        printf "data:image/%s;base64,%s" "$ext" $(openssl base64 -A -in "$img")
}

while read -r src; do
        encoded=$(encode_image "$src")
        xmlstarlet ed --inplace -u "//img[@src='$src']/@src" -v "$encoded" t.html
done < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//img/@src' -n "$htmlfile")
```

from this `t.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
                <p>bla</p>
                <img width="100%" src="./img/my_image.gif" />
                <p>otherbla</p>
                <img width="100%" src="./img/my_image2.gif" />
        </body>
</html>
```

create this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>bla</p>
    <img width="100%" src="data:image/gif;base64,iVB....="/>
    <p>otherbla</p>
    <img width="100%" src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBO...="/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course, the HTML must be correctly formatted, otherwise the parser will die.